# My catch block (async) seems to be called randomly

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, try-catch, discord

I'm encountering a very weird issue with a part of my code using async / await. This is JavaScript code used with [Discord.js library.](https://discord.js.org/#/)

Basically, there is a discord bot on my server that ask questions to newcomers, the code is a bit long so I'm just posting the part that I'm having trouble with.

The questions are asked / answered in DM. I'm using the [awaitMessages](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/DMChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages) function for this, which is specific to Discord.js. But in the code bellow, the catch function is randomly called sometimes, even if the timer is not over / max message not reached.

It's like the catch is immediatly called and I have no idea why because as I said, it seems to be random.

I'm having the issue on ~15% of questions asked by the bot, for all the others, the code enters the .then block of awaitMessages function and not the catch.

Any idea what could cause this ? I don't really know if the problem is caused by Discord.js specificly or if I missed something in the JavaScript logic. I already asked my question on the official Discord.js discord server but without success.

```js
        // send the question
        await newmsg.channel.send(questions[i]);

        // wait for the answer
        await newmsg.channel.awaitMessages(m => m.author.id === user.id, { max: 1, time: 300000, errors: ["time"], })
        .then(collected => {
          // answer given by member. The var "collected" contains the messages collected. We use .first to get the answer given

          // if questions are not canceled and the answer given is false, we stop
          if(!cancel && !checkAnswer(i, collected.first()))
          {
               badAnswer = true;
               return;
          }

        }).catch(async () => {
          await user.send(":hourglass: **End of time**";
          removeUserFromApplicants(user.id);
          cancel = true;
                    isCanceled = true;
          //console.log(`${user.username} let their application time out.`);
          logMonitoring(":clock1: Time over for **" + user.username + "**.");
        });
```

Comment: You are using await and then...catch for single function call. Use one of it. I will prefer async/await

Comment: @VikasKeskar I'm not sure to understand what you mean by "Use one of it" ? Should I not use then / catch with async / await ? What would be the equivalent ?

Comment: You can directly use ```let collected=await newmsg.channel.awaitMessages(m => m.author.id === user.id, { max: 1, time: 300000, errors: ["time"], }) ```

Comment: @VikasKeskar I see but I'm not sure how the errors would be handled ? What would be the collected value in the case of an error ? I might be missunderstanding the overall process you're thinking about. Thank you for your help

Comment: Surround code with try...catch block

Comment: So if I understand correctly, I should do :

let collected=await newmsg.channel.awaitMessages(m => m.author.id === user.id, { max: 1, time: 300000, errors: ["time"], }).try{
// code
}.catch{
// code 
}

Could you provide an example ?

Comment: Please check answer section

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
  await newmsg.channel.send(questions[i]); 
// wait for the answer 
  let collected = await newmsg.channel.awaitMessages(m => m.author.id === user.id, { max: 1, time: 300000, errors: ["time"], }) 
 if(!cancel && !checkAnswer(i, collected.first()))  { 
  badAnswer = true; return;
 }
} catch(error){
 await user.send(":hourglass: **End of time**"; removeUserFromApplicants(user.id); cancel = true; isCanceled = true; 
 logMonitoring(":clock1: Time over for **" + user.username + "**."); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the example, sadly the result is the same as the original code. The catch is randomly called sometime

Answer (score 0):

After hours of searching I sadly did not found the exact reason why both blocks were called. I highly suspect the `max: 1` to cause all this non-sense.

So what I did is surrounding the whole Promise whith a while loop. I removed the "max time" functionnality of the catch block, in other words I emptied the block. What I did is that as long as the catch block is called, we restart the "waiting process" until the bot is actually waiting for a message.

I will update if I find more informations. The solution is not perfect but it works well for now.